# Chromium still Thrashing with Larger Swap File

Tags: lubuntu, chromium, swap, chromebook

I have a new fresh install of lubuntu 22.04 on an old chromebook.  Chromium was stopping and I believe thrashing because some of the command keys still functioned.  I increased the swapfile to 4.0G and verified that it was there after reboot.  The stops continue and seem random.  System can step through pages for a long time or continuously stop requiring a reboot to get going.  I have noticed that each time I open Chromium it warns that is it not the default browser.  I click set as default but next time I open I get the same warning.  I'm not sure if this is a Chromium thing or a lubuntu thing.  Any ideas how I can get chromium working?  Chrome browser worked OK when the system had the chrome OS.

Chromebook- N3050 Braswell dual core @ 1.6GHz Memory: 2GB Storage: 16GB eMMC Expansion: MicroSD Card Reader /swapfile file 512M 342.7M - NOW WITH 4.0Gi swap

Comment: I ran sudo apt install xdg-desktop-portal-gnome.  Chromium is now accepted as the default browser and there have been no freezes.  However, video can be quite choppy.  This true of a youtube video and even just moving a curser around on the screen.

Comment: This makes no sense to me but I purged the portal-gnome.  Video ran smoother but I still have the portal-gnome type desktop.  Is there  way to recover?